# How can I implement a GetAllNodes method to return a collection of all nodes in level-order?

Tags: c#, algorithm

```
public class TreeNode<T>
{
  private List<TreeNode<T>> _children = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
  public T Data { get; set; }
  public TreeNode<T> Parent { get; private set; }
  public ReadOnlyCollection<TreeNode<T>> Children {
    get {
      return new ReadOnlyCollection<TreeNode<T>>(_children);
    }
  }
  public void AddChild(TreeNode<T> child)
  {
    _children.Add(child);
  }
  public ICollection<TreeNode<T>> GetAllNodes()
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "level-order"? First the first level, then the second, then the third, etc.? What should be the order within each level?

Comment: @MagnusGrindalBakken it's a breadth first traversal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of traversal is called [Breadth-First Traversal](http://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/c/tree/breadth-first/):

```
public ICollection<TreeNode<T>> GetAllNodes()
{
    var allNodes = new List<TreeNode<T>>();
    var queue = new Queue<TreeNode<T>>();
    queue.Enqueue(this); // will include root node

    while (queue.Any())
    {
        var current = queue.Dequeue();
        allNodes.Add(current);
        foreach (var child in current._children)
            queue.Enqueue(child);
    }

    return allNodes;
}
```

How it works: consider following tree

[image]

Lets see what queue [square brackets] will contain and what will be added to results (parentheses):

Before loop:

- root is added to queue: `[N0]`

First loop:

- first item removed from queue:
- first item added to results: `(N0)`
- all children of `N0` are added into queue: `[N1-1][N1-2]`

Second loop:

- first item `N1-1` removed from queue: `[N1-2]`
- first item added to results: `(N0)(N1-1)`
- all children of `N1-1` are added to queue: `[N1-2][N2-1]`

Third loop:

- first item `N1-2` removed from queue: `[N2-1]`
- first item added to results: `(N0)(N1-1)(N1-2)`
- all children of `N1-2` are added to queue: `[N2-1][N2-2][N2-3]`

Fourth loop:

- first item `N2-1` removed from queue: `[N2-2][N2-3]`
- first item added to results: `(N0)(N1-1)(N1-2)(N2-1)`
- all children of `N2-1` are added to queue: `[N2-2][N2-3][N3-1]`

All these items do not have children, thus further loops will only remove them one by one from queue and add to results.